# MultiValueMap causing the application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

MultiValueMap causing the application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not supported

```java
//Request Header
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

//Request Body
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("username","********");
map.add("password","*******");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;
responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:81/auth?actn=lgin",entity,String.class);
```

It thorws unauthrozied 401. Reason is appending the charset in application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace?